# Group by with Named Parameter with Spring's NamedParamterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I'm using PostgreSQL and Spring 3.1 NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

If I have some SQL which uses a named parameter in the Select & Group By clauses, Postgres will return this as bad grammar. Running the query with the parameters manually replaced will work correctly.

Assume there is a table called 'table' with 2 columns "id" and "number"

This SQL:

`SELECT some_function(id, :param), avg(number) FROM table GROUP BY some_function(id, :param)`

Becomes (as logged by the DB):

`SELECT some_function(id, $1), avg(number) FROM table GROUP BY some_function(id, $2)`

I suspect that the query planner looks at this query and it doesn't know that $1==$2, so it gives the error "column 'id' must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function."

Is there are way to get around this using Spring? Is there some way to get it so the query becomes:

`SELECT some_function(id, $1), avg(number) FROM table GROUP BY some_function(id, $1)` instead? The query planner would be okay with this I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT some_function(id, $1), avg(number) FROM table GROUP BY 1;
```

It will group by the first column (`some_function(id, $1)`) of the `SELECT` result.

Another way is to write something like this:

```
SELECT grp, avg(number)
FROM (SELECT some_function(id, $1) as grp, number FROM table)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work. The second would work for simpler SQL queries. I ended up doing manual replacements.